# Laravel, icon and name tab php, html

Tags: php, html, laravel, global-variables, adminlte

I am doing a laravel project using adminlte, is there a way to use this:

```
<title>Domínios - Iniciar Sessão</title> <link rel="icon" href="../domain.png">
```

globally, so I don´t have to put it in everypage?

The name and the icon of tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global layout that wraps all your views and includes this line. I suggest reading laravel's blade template page. This is a common problem that this feature is made for.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#extending-a-layout

Comment: I mean, yes, it is what I am doing: @extends. But I still have to use it in everypage? In Ionic I had a global page that aftected all pages